# Can I create a ranked dict by iterating over an existing dict?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, ranking

I've been searching for the answer to this for a while, but no joy.

I have a dict containing hotel names and prices.

```
mydict = {'HotelA': 100, 'HotelB': 300, 'HotelC': 200}
```

I would simply like to iterate over the dict and return a separate dict whose values rank the keys based on lowest to highest values, eg:

```
mynewdict = {'HotelA': 1, 'HotelB': 3, 'HotelC': 2}
```

I am aware of how to use `sorted` to iterate over a dictionary and provide an ordered list, but am unsure as to the best way to handle the above. All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: show us code. what have you already tried?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Python and haven't found anything I CAN try yet, hence coming here and explaining exactly what I want to do in explicit terms.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value and the builtin `enumerate` function

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>import operator
>>>mydict = {'HotelA': 100, 'HotelB': 300, 'HotelC': 200}
#Sorting a list of tuples based on their second element (the value ex.: 100, 200, 300)
>>>sorted_list = sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

In that case sorted_list will be an ordered list of tuples, each tuples containing the name of the hotel and the value:

```
[('HotelA', 100), ('HotelC', 200), ('HotelB', 300)]
```